# Powershell script to batch copy folder and incrementally rename the copied folders

Tags: powershell-ise

I've googled and keep finding solutions but cannot tweak them properly, Looking for help with my powershell solution to batch copy a sub folder called TEST0000 and copy the inputted amount to another folder called Prod with incremental folder names, eg. so copy c:\test\dba\test0000 (100 copies)  to c:\test\prod

say I wanted 100 folder copies to another folder called c:\test\prod so the names of folders in the target test\prod folder would be test0001,test0002,test0003 etc all the way to 100.

Here's what I have pieced together so far but not getting any success, it copies the folder but it names it with numbers instead of incremental folder names. So Im not seing the correct folder names in the target folder it just shows numbers as the folder name in the target directory! Help Me Please! Thanks in Advance.

```
$NumberOfFolders = Read-Host "Enter the number of Folders You need:"
$Source = "C:\Test\DBA\TEST0000"
$WhereToWrite = "C:\Test\Prod\"
for($i=1;$i -le $NumberOfFolders;$i++){
$dest = "$WhereToWrite$i"
Copy-Item $Source $dest -Recurse -Container
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Copy-Item` can't guess that you want to keep folder name. All it knows, is that you told it to copy contents of the folder `C:\Test\DBA\TEST0000` to the folder `C:\Test\Prod\1` (`C:\Test\Prod\` + `$i`). And so it does.

You have to manually add `TEST0000` to the destination path. To do so, use `Split-Path` cmdlet with `Leaf` argument on `$Source` path, it will get you the name of the last element of path (`TEST0000`). Then, add it to the destination path and add `$i` variable:

```powershell
$NumberOfFolders = Read-Host "Enter the number of Folders You need:"
$Source = "C:\Test\DBA\TEST0000"
$WhereToWrite = "C:\Test\Prod\"

for($i=1 ; $i -le $NumberOfFolders ; $i++){
    $dest = Join-Path -Path $WhereToWrite -ChildPath ((Split-Path $Source -Leaf) + $i)
    Copy-Item $Source $dest -Recurse -Container
}
```